# Wordpress login bug. Need an emergency solution

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Please help me. I need emergency solution. I can’t login in to my wordpress site. After giving username and password it redirects to site/wp-login.php and shows a blank page. It does not take to the dashboard. I have deleted all previous data from the site and installed wordpress several times. Even I have installed several versions of wordpress. But I can’t login to my admin panel in anyway. Important to mention that I have deleted ‘.htaccess file’ from the root directory of my site. I am new in wordpress. Actually I can’t understand where the problem is. Is this happening because of missing .htaccess file? Someone told me to talk with the hosting provider to solve this. Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you deleted your htaccess file?
First of all, restore the htaccess file.

In case you're not able to restore the file, proceed in this way:

- Create a new blank .htaccess file in your WordPress directory via
  FTP;
- Change permissions to 777. Log-in to your dashboard. Navigate to
  settings, permalinks, and update permalinks (choose any option
  there). When done, change the .htaccess permissions back to 644.

Then:

- Clear your browser cookies;
- Clear your browser cache.

Try to connect to your login page and see if it's working.

If it didn't work, try to:

- Open your wp-config.php file;
- Verify the DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE value and the others value like MySQL,
  Username and password (you set all these data during your first
  installation of wordpress).

Comment: thanks. Actually i am very new in wordpress and don't have any clue on .htaccess file. i deleted it mistakenly. can you please give me the sample of the .htaccess file . I mean i don't  even know hoe to write it. Please your help will be much appreciated

Comment: As i wrote above, it's really simple. Follow the instructions on my answer or check this [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-create-htaccess-files). This file is populated directly by WP so you only need to create an empty file with the correct permissions. In this way, you'll let WP to populate the file by himself.

Comment: I have done all you have told me. but no success yet. feeling helpless. I need to ready the site so urgently. But dont know how to fix all these

Comment: can you make the installation? please help. I will provide you the needed data

Comment: What does it mean? Were you able to put the htaccess file?

Comment: yeah. i have put that successfully. some are saying that the problem is associated with hosting provider . still confused. one thing to note here that i cant use ftp some days to access the root directory. so i uploaded the wordpress as compressed file loggin into the cpanel. and extracted it later but it does not work anyway. so i am getting doubt that the problem is somehow associated with hosting provider

Comment: If the connection via FTP is not stable, for sure your hosting provider is involved. You can try to installa XAMP on your PC, download what is loaded in your hosting space, download your MySQL database and install everything as local installation. In this way, you can see if something is faulty on your installation or if the external server isn't properly working.